# .NET web application intermittently stops responding and Chrome downloads 'default.html'

Tags: .net, vb.net

We have a case management web application.

One user (just one!) will occasionally experience an odd situation when moving between .aspx pages.

Moving from the 'default.aspx' page into a case ('case.aspx') will intermittently stick on the 'Loading, please wait...' splash and their Chrome browser will automatically save a document titled 'default.html'.

I'm scratching my head as I can't replicate it on anyone else's machine. Curious if it's a bug specifically with Chrome. The user has an older machine with multiple office applications running simultaneously and is close to maxing out their memory most of the time.

Comment: You could find out if it is specific to Chrome by using another browser, e.g. Firefox.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? (F12 in Chrome to show it)